# Connecting Cassandra by Hibernate in Wildfly

Tags: cassandra, hibernate-ogm, wildfly-swarm

After days of erros I hope anyone can help me out. I want to connect a cassandra (3.9) by Hibernate (5.1) to Wildfly Swarm (10.1.0). I followed the instruction from [How to package Hibernate OGM applications for WildFly 10](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/ogm/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=5.1#_on_flush_and_transactions) and added all required modules to the project.

[>>> Project repository on Github <<<](https://github.com/michael-rhoese/wildfly-cassandra-test)

After that, I added all required dependencies to the pom.xml:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Java EE 7 dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- WildFly Swarm Fractions -->


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-cassandra</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>demo</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-swarm-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.wildfly.swarm}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>package</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Next, I added the jboss-deplyoment-structure.xml:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<deployment>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.hibernate.ogm" slot="5.1" services="export" />
        <module name="org.hibernate.ogm.cassandra" slot="5.1" services="export" />
    </dependencies>
</deployment>
```

Last but not least, I added the persistence.xml:

```
<persistence
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="cassandra_fhe_prd_pu" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>

    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    <properties>
        <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.hibernate:5.1"/>

        <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="JBossTS" />

        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" value="cassandra_experimental"/>


        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.hosts" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database" value="any"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Every post I read tells me thats all I have to do. But if I start the application following message is shown:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (main) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: (("deployment" => "demo.war")) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.null"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"demo.war#cassandra_fhe_prd_pu\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.null]"]
}
```

==========================

Full output:

```
    2017-04-18 13:17:34,022 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction:                      JCA - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:jca:2017.4.0
    2017-04-18 13:17:34,022 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction:                  Logging - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:logging:2017.4.0
    2017-04-18 13:17:34,022 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction:          Bean Validation - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:bean-validation:2017.4.0
    2017-04-18 13:17:34,022 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction:                   JAX-RS - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:jaxrs:2017.4.0
    2017-04-18 13:17:34,022 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction:                      JPA - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:jpa:2017.4.0
    2017-04-18 13:17:34,022 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction:        CDI Configuration - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:cdi-config:2017.4.0
    2017-04-18 13:17:34,022 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction:                      CDI - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:cdi:2017.4.0
    2017-04-18 13:17:34,022 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction:              Datasources - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:datasources:2017.4.0
    2017-04-18 13:17:34,022 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction:             Transactions - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:transactions:2017.4.0
    2017-04-18 13:17:34,022 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction:                 Undertow - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:undertow:2017.4.0
    2017-04-18 13:17:40,410 WARN  [org.wildfly.swarm.datasources] (main) WFSWARM1005: Not creating a default datasource due to lack of JDBC driver
    2017-04-18 13:17:40,894 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
    2017-04-18 13:17:40,957 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Swarm 2017.4.0 (WildFly Core 2.2.1.Final) starting
    2017-04-18 13:17:41,144 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFSWARM0019: Install MSC service for command line args: []
    2017-04-18 13:17:50,956 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
    2017-04-18 13:17:50,956 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
    2017-04-18 13:17:50,956 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 24) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
    2017-04-18 13:17:50,971 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=4.9.6.Final
    2017-04-18 13:17:50,971 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 18) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 16 core threads with 128 task threads based on your 8 available processors
    2017-04-18 13:17:51,002 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.3.4.Final)
    2017-04-18 13:17:51,018 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
    2017-04-18 13:17:51,409 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.4.11.Final starting
    2017-04-18 13:17:51,424 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-8) XNIO version 3.4.3.Final
    2017-04-18 13:17:51,424 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-8) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.4.3.Final
    2017-04-18 13:17:51,487 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
    2017-04-18 13:17:51,518 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0]:8080
    2017-04-18 13:17:52,624 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Swarm 2017.4.0 (WildFly Core 2.2.1.Final) started in 11761ms - Started 110 of 120 services (21 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
    2017-04-18 13:18:04,528 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm.runtime.deployer] (main) deploying demo.war
    2017-04-18 13:18:04,544 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "demo.war" (runtime-name: "demo.war")
    2017-04-18 13:18:20,191 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for cassandra_fhe_prd_pu
    2017-04-18 13:18:25,686 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0018: Deployment "deployment.demo.war" is using a private module ("org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
    2017-04-18 13:18:25,686 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0018: Deployment "deployment.demo.war" is using a private module ("org.jboss.jts:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
    2017-04-18 13:18:26,201 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (main) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: (("deployment" => "demo.war")) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.null"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"demo.war#cassandra_fhe_prd_pu\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.null]"]
    }
    2017-04-18 13:18:26,201 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (main) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "demo.war" was rolled back with the following failure message:
    {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.null"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"demo.war#cassandra_fhe_prd_pu\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.null]"]
    }
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,045 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment demo.war (runtime-name: demo.war) in 838ms
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,045 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (main) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
    WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
    service jboss.naming.context.java.null (missing) dependents: [service jboss.persistenceunit."demo.war#cassandra_fhe_prd_pu"]
    service jboss.persistenceunit."demo.war#cassandra_fhe_prd_pu" (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."demo.war".POST_MODULE]

    2017-04-18 13:18:27,045 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTP listener default suspending
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,045 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTP listener default stopped, was bound to [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0]:8080
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,045 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0004: Undertow 1.4.11.Final stopping
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,061 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0050: WildFly Swarm 2017.4.0 (WildFly Core 2.2.1.Final) stopped in 7ms
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,076 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (main) WELD-ENV-002001: Weld SE container internal shut down
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,076 ERROR [stderr] (main) java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,076 ERROR [stderr] (main)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,076 ERROR [stderr] (main)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,076 ERROR [stderr] (main)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,076 ERROR [stderr] (main)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,076 ERROR [stderr] (main)    at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.MainInvoker.invoke(MainInvoker.java:39)
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,076 ERROR [stderr] (main)    at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.run(Main.java:46)
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,076 ERROR [stderr] (main)    at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.main(Main.java:37)
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,076 ERROR [stderr] (main) Caused by: org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: WFSWARM0004: Deployment failed: {"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.null"],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"demo.war#cassandra_fhe_prd_pu\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.null]"]}
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,076 ERROR [stderr] (main)    at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:278)
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,076 ERROR [stderr] (main)    at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:94)
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,076 ERROR [stderr] (main)    at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.deploy(Unknown Source)
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,076 ERROR [stderr] (main)    at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.deploy(Swarm.java:443)
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,076 ERROR [stderr] (main)    at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.main(Swarm.java:611)
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,076 ERROR [stderr] (main)    ... 7 more
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,076 ERROR [stderr] (main) Caused by: org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: WFSWARM0004: Deployment failed: {"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.null"],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"demo.war#cassandra_fhe_prd_pu\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.null]"]}
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,076 ERROR [stderr] (main)    at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:273)
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,076 ERROR [stderr] (main)    ... 11 more
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,076 ERROR [stderr] (main) Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,076 ERROR [stderr] (main)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,076 ERROR [stderr] (main)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,076 ERROR [stderr] (main)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,076 ERROR [stderr] (main)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,076 ERROR [stderr] (main)    at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.MainInvoker.invoke(MainInvoker.java:39)
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,076 ERROR [stderr] (main)    at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.run(Main.java:46)
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,076 ERROR [stderr] (main)    at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.main(Main.java:37)
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,076 ERROR [stderr] (main) Caused by: org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: WFSWARM0004: Deployment failed: {"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.null"],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"demo.war#cassandra_fhe_prd_pu\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.null]"]}
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,092 ERROR [stderr] (main)    at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:278)
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,092 ERROR [stderr] (main)    at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:94)
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,092 ERROR [stderr] (main)    at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.deploy(Unknown Source)
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,092 ERROR [stderr] (main)    at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.deploy(Swarm.java:443)
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,092 ERROR [stderr] (main)    at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.main(Swarm.java:611)
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,092 ERROR [stderr] (main)    ... 7 more
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,092 ERROR [stderr] (main) Caused by: org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: WFSWARM0004: Deployment failed: {"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.null"],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"demo.war#cassandra_fhe_prd_pu\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.null]"]}
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,092 ERROR [stderr] (main)    at    org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:273)
    2017-04-18 13:18:27,092 ERROR [stderr] (main)    ... 11 more

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

After comment I added the Datastax JDBC wrapper as following:

project-stages.yml

```
swarm:
  datasources:
    data-sources:
      CassandraDS:
        driver-name: cassandra
        connection-url: jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9160/system?version=3.9
    jdbc-drivers:
      cassandra:
        driver-class-name: org.apache.cassandra2.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver
        xa-datasource-name: com.github.adejanovski.cassandra.jdbc.CassandraDataSource
        driver-module-name: org.github.adejanovski.cassandra
```

module.xml

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.github.adejanovski.cassandra">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="cassandra-jdbc-wrapper-3.1.0.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="slf4j-jdk14-1.7.24.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="sun.jdk" export="true" >
            <imports>
                <include path="sun/misc/Unsafe" />
            </imports>
        </module>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.hibernate.ogm" slot="5.1" services="export" />
            <module name="org.hibernate.ogm.cassandra" slot="5.1" services="export" />
            <module name="org.github.adejanovski.cassandra" slot="main" services="export" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

and the persistence.xml

```
<persistence
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="cassandra_fhe_prd_pu" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/CassandraDS</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.hibernate:5.1"/>

            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="JBossTS"/>

            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" value="cassandra_experimental"/>

            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.hosts" value="localhost"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database" value="fhe"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Now, the error message says:

```
WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "CassandraDS")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.cassandra"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "org.wildfly.data-source.CassandraDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.cassandra]",
        "jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/CassandraDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.cassandra]"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you checked this one? https://developer.jboss.org/thread/274131?_sscc=t It looks like you are only missing some wildfly setup since the jdbc driver for cassandra can't be found.

Comment: Yes I had. I did it but the new error says that the module for the driver is missing.

Comment: ok it's a start ;) can you update the question and put new error in.

Comment: Can you check the http://stackoverflow.com/a/39296714/7413631 (it's about other driver) but looks very similar to your problem, basically check that the jar is in the module folder.

Comment: I think the jar is on the right place. I added a link to the repository so you are able to take a look inside.

Comment: might it be that you need to set https://github.com/michael-rhoese/wildfly-cassandra-test/blob/master/src/main/resources/project-stages.yml#L9 to com.github.adejanovski.cassandra.jdbc.CassandraDriver too?

Comment: I know if not hibernate ignores the custom jdbc driver. It is required to specify a datasource with driver-setting. I check it and tell you the result

Comment: Hibernate OGM does not uses Datasources or JDBC driver, it creates a connection using the information in the properties. You don't have to specify a datastore or jdbc driver

Comment: As a standalone war it could be right. If I pack the war into a -swarm.jar wildly wants to create a datasource for hibernate (see full output after fraction list). That's the reason hibernate ogm fails after reading persistence. Feel free to tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For now I find a solution. I don't know if it is the best way but it works:

First I add the required fractions without swarm jpa. After that I remove the cassandra-jdbc-wrapper. Now hibernate creates the connection directly and persists the entity. The only bad think I has to do was to add the entity class to the persistence xml.

The working project is pushed to the repository. I will play with swarm and hope to find a better way.